# Reading Category attribute inside test method using Reflection

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0, reflection

I'm trying to add test methods using the category property of the `TestMethod` custom attribute by reading a .dll using reflection, something like this:

if the test method is:

```
[TestMethod, Category("xyz"), Category("abc")]
public void VerifySomething()
{
   //some code
}
```

I'm reading the .dll using reflection like this:

```
 Assembly _assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(AssembleyPath);
            Type[] types = _assembly.GetExportedTypes();
            foreach (Type type in types)
            {
                Attribute _classAttribute = type.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(TestClassAttribute));
                if (_classAttribute != null)
                {
                    TreeNode _n = new TreeNode();
                    _n.Text = type.Name;
                    if (type.Name.ToLower().Contains("testbase"))
                        // For exculding test base class from tree node list
                        continue;
                    MemberInfo[] members =
                        type.GetMembers(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod);
                    foreach (MemberInfo member in members)
                    {

                            Attribute _att = member.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(TestMethodAttribute));
                            if (_att != null)
                            {
                                TestMethod _t = new TestMethod(member.Name);

                            }

                    }
                 }
            }
```

Using this i'm unable to add test methods filtered by particular category inside treeview node.
Basically all i want is to read TestCategoryAttribute from dll which has value something like "xyz" or "abc" as per the example i've mentioned above and then based on the filter (TestCategoryAttribute) value i would want to load methods from the dll and add them to the treeview node. Can anybody please guide me how can i achieve that.

Comment: I'm unable to read TestCategoryAttribute based on which i'll be filtering the  TestMethods and then add them to the tree node

Comment: While reading from dll i'm getting all the test methods but i'm unable to get test category

Comment: It is populating correctly. Its not null

Comment: I've added the actual working code above. 
The desired result is :
Based in the TestCategoryAttribute value i want to filter test methods which i'll be adding them to the tree. For instance in the above mentioned test method, i want only those test methods which has category "xyz" and not those methods which has category "def"

Comment: Current result is i'm getting all the test methods from the dll and i'm unable to filter values based on the TestCategoryAttribute, Its coming null when i try to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how to get a `TestMethod` as a `MethodInfo` from [Reflection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8zz808e6(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
var _t= typeof(testClass).GetMethod(methodName); // testClass should be the type in your foreach
```

Given a `TestMethod` `_t` (assuming everything is right till there), you can get the categories with the following

```
var testCategories = IEnumerable<TestCategoryAttribute>)_t.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TestCategoryAttribute), true));
```

How to filter them based on some conditions?
Does a Linq [Any](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972(v=vs.110).aspx) do the trick?

```
    if testCategories.Any(c => c == "xyz" || c == "abc") )
    {
        // then add to the treeview node, etc...
```

Comment: getting this error on _t after inserting your line after this step -
TestMethod _t = new TestMethod(member.Name);
string key = string.Format("K{0}", TotalCountOfTests++); 
var testCategories = (IEnumerable<TestCategoryAttribute>)_t.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TestCategoryAttribute), true);

Error CS1929 'TestMethod' does not contain a definition for 'GetCustomAttributes' and the best extension method overload 'CustomAttributeExtensions.GetCustomAttributes(MemberInfo, Type, bool)' requires a receiver of type 'MemberInfo' :(

Comment: Have you seen this part: `var _t= typeof(testClass).GetMethod(methodName); `? testClass should be your type in the foreach but I don't know if you have the methodName yet...

Comment: I'm already getting the method name here -
TestMethod _t = new TestMethod(member.Name);

Comment: That's wrong indeed :) You need to get the method from reflection so that you can read the categories

Comment: try `var _t = typeof(type).GetMethod("VerifySomething");` or maybe `member.Name` instead of `"VerifySomething"` ... use also the debugger to choose... and then my code to get the categories...

Comment: Thanks Man! This did the trick. Added this code to get method name -
var _t = type.GetMethod(member.Name); and voila 
var testCategories = _t.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TestCategoryAttribute), true);
Yielded results. Thank You very much. I'll mark your answer the best answer :)